# Can't use Composer environment after re-enabling service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have been trying to find a way to save on the costs of Airflow by disabling it when not in use.  I have discovered that if we disable the `composer.googleapis.com` service while not in use that Google does not charge for the service while it is disabled, although it does continue to charge for other resources that are still active.  Unfortunately, if the service is disabled for more than an hour or so, the service is not usable after re-enabling it.  After the service has been disabled for an extended period of time, the Composer Environment Details Page shows

> An error occurred with retrieving the last operation on this environment

and

> This environment cannot be edited due to the errors that occurred during environment creation/update. Please investigate the logs to determine the cause, or create a new environment.

And `gcloud composer environments describe` shows `state: ERROR`

The one error that I did see in the logs was due to a duplicate key when the `airflow_monitoring` DAG was rescheduled after a little over an hour.  Therefore, created a new Composer environment, disabled all DAGs, disabled the composer service, waited a while, then enabled it again.  The environment was once again in an error state.

The [Cloud Composer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/enabling-service#before_you_begin) states:

> If you disable the Cloud Composer API, environments become unusable within an hour of service deactivation unless you re-enable the API. If you re-enable the API, you are billed for the service usage that occurs while the Cloud Composer service is deactivating.

Maybe this is poorly worded, but to me it sounds like it would become unusable within an hour if you disable it, but if you re-enabled it anytime later, it will become usable again. I am wondering if it really means that if you disable it, you must re-enable it within 1 hour or it will become permanently unusable.

Is there a way to disable the `composer.googleapis.com` service for longer than an hour and then get it working again after the service has been re-enabled? Is there something I can restart, or some way to clear the error state?  Is there more I should do before disabling it?

I am using `composer-1.10.4-airflow-1.10.6` with Python 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your GCP Composer version (`composer-a.b.c-airflow-x.y.z`)?

Comment: @mk_sta. I am using `composer-1.10.4-airflow-1.10.6` with Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to disable the `composer.googleapis.com` service for more than an hour and then have environments be functional after re-enablement.

GCP services are not meant to be enabled/disabled on the fly in this manner, and disablement of a service is meant to be performed with the intention of disabling it for the long term. Keeping a service disabled for long enough means Google-managed components created for the service (specifically for your project) will be decommissioned, and in Composer's case, this will render your environments permanently unusable.

The error state in the environment cannot be cleared. If you want to save on costs, you should delete Composer environments as opposed to deactivating the service entirely. The "service" is not cluster-like and isn't meant to be toggled on and off.